# Calculate each row table from foreach using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have foreach loop (rails) in Table that I want to calculate each row from one input text.

I have already tried to create jquery but it only calculate first row of the table.

The expected output for this is, it must see each row calculated from input text keyup

```
 <input type = "text" class = "share_amount" id = "alldata" >
 <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
 <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Share</th>
    <th>Result</th>
 </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>                                   
<% @userfile.each do |info|%>
<tr class = "itemrow">
  <td><%= info.name %></td>
  <td class = "price1"><%= info.amount %></td>
  <td><%= info.share %></td>
  <td class = "result"></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input#alldata").keyup(function() {
                var share = this.value;
                $('tr.itemrow').each(function () {
                   $(this).find('.price1').each(function(){
                      var tdval = $(this).text();
                      $(".result").text(share * tdval);
                 });     
              });
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Comment: Think you have too many `.each()` running. You're seeking 'price1' in the row, are there more than 1? Does not appear that way, so I would not use `.each()` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `.each()`, make sure to not over do it. Also, for this usage, it is helpful to pass in the index and element or use `this`.

Consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input#alldata").keyup(function(e) {
    var share = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('tr.itemrow').each(function(i, el) {
      var val = share * parseFloat($(".price1", el).html());
      $(".result", el).html(val.toFixed(2));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="share_amount" id="alldata">
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Share</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="itemrow">
      <td>
        Name 1
      </td>
      <td class="price1">
        1.50
      </td>
      <td>
        Share 1
      </td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="itemrow">
      <td>
        Name 2
      </td>
      <td class="price1">
        2.75
      </td>
      <td>
        Share 2
      </td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="itemrow">
      <td>
        Name 3
      </td>
      <td class="price1">
        4.00
      </td>
      <td>
        Share 3
      </td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The value of a text field will be a String type. It was not clear if the user was going to enter a integer or a float value, but since we're working with Prices, I figured it might be either. I used `parseFloat()` to convert the value entered into a Float.

In the `.each()` lookp, I can select just the specific class items using $("select", element)`style selection. Similar to`$(element).find()`. No real difference, just less code in my opinion.

Read in the price from the table and convert it into another Float value. Calculate the desired value and place it into the result column for that row. I use `.toFixed()` to help round out or display the float value (if currency).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the result that I'm looking for Thanks a lot. You save my day. I was confused jquery .each .  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigneed which `.result` do you mean wehn using   $`(".result").text(share * tdval);` I suggest he following changes to access to the desired `.result` in the same row:

```
<script>
//....
     $('tr.itemrow').each(function () {

           $(this).find('.price1').each(function(){
               var tdval = parseInt($(this).text()); //use parseInt to convert it to a number
           });

          $(this).find(".result").text(share * tdval);
    })
//...
</script>
```

Finally I think there is no need to loop through price because there is only one price on each row.

Comment: Might be hard to do math with Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Following points will help you,

1. Your each row of table is having same class which is real problem for your goal. So define different class for each row of table.
2. `class` is slower selector for search in `JS` so use `id` instead of it.

Following can provide separate id index to each row.

```
<% @userfile.each_with_index do |info, i|%>
  <tr id = "itemrow-#{i+1}">
    <td><%= info.name %></td>
    <td id = "price-#{i+1}"><%= info.amount %></td>
```

3. Use `$("[id^='itemrow']")` & `$("[id^='price']")` in your js code later  as per [doc](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
4. Additional: If your instance `@userfile` is collection object, then it should be plural. Make it appropriate as `@userfiles`
5. Rest is your part of efforts.

Comment: i think i missed this. let me check and get back to you. thanks

Comment: @ray using Classes are still helpful for selecting large groupings and also for styling. this is not to say IDs are bad, yet maybe not best for this use case.

Comment: @Twisty I will surely note it down to check it further as I not having good exp in JS. Perhaps any reference to clarify it will be appriciated :)

Comment: @ray I will see if I can find a good reference. It's really just a matter of what you're looking to do. Selecting by ID can be great to select one unique item. But if you need to grab a group of elements, attribute or class selection helps.

Answer (score 0):

In html give path for "jquery/min.js" then perform keyup events
    //html

```
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>    
<input type = "text" class = "share_amount" id = "alldata" >
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Share</th>
  <th>Result</th>
 </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>                                   
  <tr class="itemrow">
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td class="price1">10000</td>
    <td>Share1</td>
    <td class="result"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="itemrow">
    <td>ABC2</td>
    <td class="price1">20000</td>
    <td>Share2</td>
    <td class="result"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

//jquery

$("#alldata").keyup(function() {
var share = this.value;
 $('tr.itemrow').each(function () {
  $(this).find('.price1').each(function(){
   var tdval = $(this).text();
   $(".result").text(share * tdval);
  });     
 });
});
```

Comment: When posting an answer, it is often best to explain or provide a bit of extra info fo OP or other users that find this post.